# Play sound without interrupting other playing sounds (VBA)

Tags: vba, audio, powerpoint

I have a code that can play a sound in a PowerPoint presentation, but If I make it play 2 sounds one after another, the first one will stop and the second one will play. So the first sound was interrupted by the second sound.

I tried experimenting with different Flags but none does one I want to achieve. I'm currently using the SND_ASYNC flag.

Here's the current code (in a module):

```
#If VBA7 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long
#Else
Public Declare Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long
#End If

Sub playSound(SoundFile As String)
sndPlaySound32 SoundFile, SND_ASYNC
End Sub
```

I want to have a version of the code that plays a sound and only makes it stop when it's finished and doesn't get interrupted by another sound.

Comment: Try [WMPlayer.OCX](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+VBA+WMPlayer.OCX)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Try examples by the link I provided. Post the code if you stuck.

Comment: I tried `Set Wmp = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")` but it returns the error "Automation error".

Comment: Try `CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")`

Comment: Same error "Automation error".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191919/discussion-between-omegastripes-and-daniel-climaco).

Comment: Ok. I'm waiting there for you.